# How would I create this EditorTemplate for a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have a custom ViewModel (`CompanySalaryDataViewModel`) that has a collection of other ViewModels on it (`PersonalIncomeViewModel`). **Ultimately, I want to have an EditorTemplate for a `CompanySalaryDataViewModel` that consumes an EditorTemplate for a `PersonalIncomeViewModel` somehow in a way that it provides 2-way binding to my ViewModel when it's passed back into my POST controller.**

For example, let's say it's something like this:

```
public class CompanySalaryDataViewModel
{
    string CompanyName { get; set; }
    IList<PersonalIncomeViewModel> AllSalaryData { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalIncomeViewModel
{
    long UniqueID { get; set; }
    string PersonName { get; set; }
    int JanIncome { get; set; }
    int FebIncome { get; set; }
    int MarIncome { get; set; }
    int AprIncome { get; set; }
    int MayIncome { get; set; }
    int JunIncome { get; set; }
    int JulIncome { get; set; }
    int AugIncome { get; set; }
    int SepIncome { get; set; }
    int OctIncome { get; set; }
    int NovIncome { get; set; }
    int DecIncome { get; set; }
}
```

I want this done in a way where it's similar to the following markup but works:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName) %>
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="t-grid-header">
                <th class="t-header">ID</th>
                <th class="t-header">Person</th>
                <th class="t-header">Jan</th>
                <th class="t-header">Feb</th>
                <th class="t-header">Mar</th>
                <th class="t-header">Apr</th>
                <th class="t-header">May</th>
                <th class="t-header">Jun</th>
                <th class="t-header">Jul</th>
                <th class="t-header">Aug</th>
                <th class="t-header">Sep</th>
                <th class="t-header">Oct</th>
                <th class="t-header">Nov</th>
                <th class="t-header">Dec</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <%
    var isAlt = false;
    foreach (var salaryData in Model.AllSalaryData)
    {
        var salary = salaryData;
        if (isAlt)
        {%>
            <tr class="t-alt">
        <%
        }
        else
        {%>
            <tr>
        <%
        }

        isAlt = !isAlt;
        %>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.UniqueID)%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.PersonName)%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.JanIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_1", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.FebIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_2", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.MarIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_3", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.AprIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_4", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.MayIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_5", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.JunIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_6", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.JulIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_7", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.AugIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_8", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.SepIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_9", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.OctIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_10", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.NovIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_11", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
                <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => salary.DecIncome, new {id = salary.PersonName + "_12", style = "width: 45px;"})%></td>
            </tr>
    <%
    }%>
    </table>
```

The problems with this code are:

1. Each "January" textbox has the same name (`salary.JanIncome` - doesn't include anything to differentiate it from another salary). Same problem with every month.
2. Perhaps because of problem #1, this doesn't bind back to the ViewModel when I post - my `AllSalaryData` collection is null.
3. All of this seems VERY non-best-practice and like there should be a better way to do this.

Ultimately, I guess I need to better understand using templates with collections but the other part of it is the "logic" to properly apply the `t-alt` class to the appropriate table row.

NOTE #1: I set the HTML IDs this way for some javascript stuff I have interacting with these textboxes.

NOTE #2: I'm not really doing this with salary data.

Comment: Okay, so I have found a function solution that's not ideal but it works. Apparently the `foreach` is the problem but a `for(var i=0; i < xxx.Count; i++)` works because the index number gets used for generation of the `name` of the rendered control. Functions now, but I'd like to do this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have found a function solution that's not ideal but it works. Apparently the `foreach` is the problem but a `for(var i=0; i < xxx.Count; i++)` works because the index number gets used for generation of the name of the rendered control. Not ideal but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with your question:
1. 'ViewModels' are view models - at least from design point of view. Is your intent to be able to 'batch' update the collection/list or your post back to send collection of the same object type?
2. Let's assume your model - PersonalIncome[ViewModel] is persistable. So, you will be editing one record at time and the editor template you will be using will be just for an item in the collection.

Can you elaborate the intent not just what you want to do - there could be other alternatives than creating a 'list' view with Textboxes.

Comment: Alternatives aren't an option - business requirements are for all of this to be editable at once (for good reason). I have another grid that's AJAX bound that is performing add'l ajax lookups to insert data into and perform javascript math with the data in all of these textboxes on a massive scale but I need the ability to give the end user the final ability to hand-edit the final number. This dynamically-generated "textbox grid" will only have ~10 rows. The inputs, however, are selected in very large quantities. Focus on the problem I've presented and you can ignore all of that, though.